# XML Schema and XML in one file?

Tags: xml, xsd

Can I put my XML and XML Schema in one file? Or the schema has to be separate file? Im new to XML

I have noticed from tutorials that they have an XML file (.xml) and a separate XML Schema file (.xsd). Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can have xsd and xml in a same file such declaration is called as **Inline Schema definition**.

But as per general practice they are kept outside for many reasons, one of the very famous reason is:

- Reusablility

Lets say you want to generate the sample    xml/POJOs from the xsd for later.(Applies only for Java) (example JAXB)

Also as a best practice one should break the complex xsd into smaller xsd for easy to read and understand + flexibility of plugin the xsd required in a given case.

Comment: Another good reason is that if A sends an XML file to B and B wants to validate it, B wants to validate it against a schema that B trusts, not against any old schema that happens to come with the document.